# Can't send a POST using JSON

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am working in a django app with rest framework. I need to add a new row in table via json, but this table is a child of the other table.

when i try to send "POST" the app returns this error:
... may not be NULL

image > https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31258353/addnewrow.jpg

MODELS:

```
 # Create your models here.
    class sequence(models.Model):
        number = models.CharField(max_length=3)
        word = models.CharField(max_length=1)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


    class localization(models.Model):
        sequence = models.ForeignKey(sequence)
        init = models.CharField(max_length=3)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

FORM:

```
    class sequenceform(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = sequence


    class localizationform(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = localization
```

SERIALIZE:

```
class sequenceserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = sequence
        fields = ("pk","number","word","name")

class localizationserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = localization
        fields = ("id","init","name")
```

VIEW:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def sequencelistjson(request, format=None):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        prj = sequence.objects.all()
        serializer = sequenceserializer(prj, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = sequenceserializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def localizationlistjson(request, seq_id, format=None):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        seq = get_object_or_404(sequence, pk=seq_id)
        loc = seq.localization_set.order_by('init')
        serializer = localizationserializer(loc, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = localizationserializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: First, with "rest framework" did you mean django-rest-framework? Second, the image you included is broken (I'm getting a 404 error). Third, can you please describe well the request you're doing (url, body, headers)?

Comment: yes, django rest - framework.

Comment: img - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31258353/addnewrow.jpg

Comment: Try adding `parsers.JSONParser` to your view and see if it's working. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#parsers

Comment: I have no idea why you went to the bother of making that screenshot collage, blurring it, etc, rather than simply *cutting and pasting the traceback text* which would have been far more useful.

Comment: Just a friendly bit of advice, model (and other class) names are usually `PascalCase` (caps for the first letter of each word). You can also copy the traceback from the Django debug page without revealing too much information. A picture of a traceback isn't searchable and makes it very difficult to figure out what calls are being made. The lack of other information (like the input) in your question also made it difficult to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to create a `localization` object, but it requires that a `sequence` exists (seen by the `ForeignKey`).

In your serializer you are not specifying a field for the `sequence`, so Django REST framework has no clue that one is required. Because you are not associated the `sequence` elsewhere, when Django REST framework tries to create the `localization` object the `sequence` is being sent as `NULL`. This isn't allowed, as the `ForeignKey` does not have `null=True` set (it's required).

You can fix this either by adding `null=True` to the `sequence` field, if it isn't actually required. The other option, which is most likely what you want, is to include the `sequence` field in the `Meta.fields` options on the serializer.